# Why _SC_AIO_MAX is well-defined while sysconf(_SC_AIO_MAX) return -1?

Tags: c, posix, aio

Here is a simple demo:

```cpp
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
#ifdef _SC_AIO_MAX
    printf("_SC_AIO_MAX is defined\n");
if (sysconf(_SC_AIO_MAX) == -1)
{
    printf("unsupported\n");
    printf("_SC_AIO_MAX = %d\n", _SC_AIO_MAX);
    printf("sysconf(_SC_AIO_MAX) = %d\n", sysconf(_SC_AIO_MAX));
}
#else
    printf("_SC_AIO_MAX is undefined\n");
#endif
return 0;
}
```

output:

> _SC_AIO_MAX is defined
>   unsupported
>   _SC_AIO_MAX = 24
>   sysconf(_SC_AIO_MAX) = -1

live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7GDzyvEUgRwMHX95

As you can see, `_SC_AIO_MAX` is defined to be `24`, but `sysconf(_SC_AIO_MAX)` returns `-1`. 
According `man 3 sysconf`

```
       *  If  name  corresponds  to a maximum or minimum limit, and that limit is indeterminate, -1 is re‐
          turned and errno is not changed.  (To distinguish an indeterminate limit from an error, set  er‐
          rno to zero before the call, and then check whether errno is nonzero when -1 is returned.)
```

But the limit has been defined to be `24`, why does sysconf still return `-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_SC_AIO_MAX = 24` is not the value of the limit, it's the identifier of the limit that you would like to access.

`getconf(24) == -1` means either:

1. There is an error (check `errno` to see if there was an error); or
2. That the limit is indeterminate.

Some documentation mentions that you should set `errno` to `0` before calling `getconf` to make sure you can tell the difference between these two cases.

(2) might happen when functionality is available but has been disable, etc.

Comment: Thanks, thsutton! Is there any way to know why the identifier of the limit that I want to access is not accessible? Can it to be simply concluded that linux doesn't support _SC_AIO_MAX?

Comment: @陳力 You check the source code (if you have access to it). You've mentioned Linux, so I guess you are probably using glibc. Here's the implementation: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/sysconf.c;h=47afac96142f8f1df21f31e47d90bd74350999e4;hb=0a8262a1b269f8f1602933248e69dfb041aab7a2#l175 As you can see, this version of glibc doesn't support that limit.